# Use external ActiveMQ broker as trigger for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, activemq-classic

We are considering switching from a constantly running ECS task that listens to topics on the foreign broker (not managed by us), to AWS Lambda which shall be triggered by messages on specific topics.

I know it is possible to use AmazonMQ with EventSource for Lambda, but only if the AmazonMQ broker is running in the same AWS account as the Lambda.

Is it possible to use an external ActiveMQ broker (foreign AWS account or even non-AWS, on-premise) in conjunction with a trigger for AWS Lambda?

The ActiveMQ broker is generally reachable from AWS resources as the ECS task runs like a charm.

Comment: There is no built in way to trigger a Lambda function from such an external source. I think your best course of action would be to have your application send a message to a supported AWS service, such as AWS SNS, or trigger the Lambda function directly.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I do not have access to the broker side. We're only consumers. What we could do is have a tiny ECS task that listens on the topics and dispatches the incoming messages to an EventBus... But in that case I guess I can just put the lambda functions into the ECS task too... I'll keep thinking about it some more. Thank you!